# How can I get a person's country from this database?

Tags: mysql, select

I'm having a real bad time with an assignment with a given database, a fake simulator on Mysql. My problem is, I need a Query to get the data from a client's Country, but Client's table only contains a City data. Tables are:

```
tbl_Client:
/ ID*
/ Name
/ Birthday
/ ID_City (FK)

tbl_City:
/ ID_City *
/ vchCityName
/ ID_State (FK)

tbl_State:
/ ID_State *
/ vchStateName
/ ID_intRegion (FK)

tbl_Region:
/ ID_Region *
/ vchRegionName
/ ID_Country (FK)

tbl_Country:
/ ID_Country *
/ vchCountryName
```

So, my question is, how can I get a Client's country to compare it with other data? (The big question is comparing a client's nationality with a musician they prefer, but what I can't seem to manage is the client part). I was trying something very basic, but it doesn't work.

```
(...)tbl_Client CL, tbl_City CT, tbl_State ST, tbl_Region R, tbl_Country C
WHERE CT.ID_City = ST.ID_City 
AND ST.ID_Region = R.ID_Region 
AND R.ID_Contry = C.ID_Contry
```

And then I tried to compare that C.ID_Country, and well, I tried a lot of things and still got nothing... I would really appreciate if someone could enlighten me on this.

Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Come on. This is basic stuff. We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: You aren't that far away try replacing comma separated joins with proper joins.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks a lot! So it is the same as scaisEdge says. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this you get all the data in relation

```
select tbl_Client.*, tbl_City.*, tbl_State.*, tbl_Region.*, tbl_Country.*
from tbl_Client
inner join tbl_City on tbl_Client.ID_City = tbl_City.ID_City
inner join tbl_State on tbl_State.ID_State = tbl_City.ID_State
INNER join tbl_Region on tbl_Region.ID_Region = tbl_State.ID_Region
INNER join tbl_Country on tbl_Country.ID_Country =tbl_Region.ID_Country;
```

if you need the country for a client ID eg id = 3

```
select tbl_Client.* , tbl_Country.*
from tbl_Client
inner join tbl_City on tbl_Client.ID_City = tbl_City.ID_City
inner join tbl_State on tbl_State.ID_State = tbl_City.ID_State
INNER join tbl_Region on tbl_Region.ID_Region = tbl_State.ID_Region
INNER join tbl_Country on tbl_Country.ID_Country =tbl_Region.ID_Country
where tbl_Client.ID = 3;
```

Comment: I'm really grateful you took the time to do this, thanks a lot @scaisEdge ! I was having a really hard time with this simple thing, but now I surely won't forget this in my lifetime. Thank you!!